# one-way anova, one group has no variance

Tags: anova

I have 20 genotypes for comparison (each has n >or= 5), however one group (control) has no variation (each sample = 100%). Can I apply one-way anova in this case. If not, what test would be better. Thanks.

Comment: It might help to understand the reasons for no variation in the control.  Is this due to insensitive measurements?  A detection limit?  Or maybe it is intrinsic heteroscedasticity (differences in dispersion between groups) brought on by a need to re-express the data on a different scale, such as a square root, logarithm, or reciprocal?  Writing your thoughts about this matter will help guide people towards appropriate, effective answers.  (What exactly does "each sample = 100%" mean, BTW?)

Comment: I know, the design of experiments was far from perfect. Unfortunately, I do not have the raw data for control group. The control was a priori taken as 100% of (say) expression of the particular gene. All other 20 genotypes were measured for 5 to 7 times (independent repetitions) and definitely have some variation.

Answer (score 1):

You say that the control group has 100%, is your outcome really numeric? or is it categorical?  if the later then maybe a Chisquared test or Fisher's exact test would be more appropriate.  If you don't have specific yes/no type answers, but still have values that are in the 0-1 or 0%-100% range with no chance of going outside of the range, then maybe a beta regression (which will be like one-way anova if you use dummy variables) would be more appropriate.